# Join tables but only for the first row that has the same Id

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables with information about each SKU (product): TransactionTable and PositionTable (see image below).

[image]

I tried a bunch of methods to join the 2 tables but I keep getting the result seen in InCorrectSkusPositionAndNrTran. I want to get the result seen in CorrectSkusPositionAndNrTran.

The reason I want the second result is because it will give me an accurate representation of the number of transactions per SKU so I can sum them up.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Most RDBMSs except SQLite and MySQL have `rank()` and/or `row_number()` window functions. Those should get you what you need.

Comment: Pardon me if im wrong, By seeing the example. it seems there is no significance for entires B and C in the PositionTable. <br/>In PositionTable if there is an entry for for the pair 3-B instead of 3-A, will the CorrectOutput has 3 -30 in the resultset ?

Answer (score 0):

Tried the below on Teradata:
 `SELECT`
 `POS.SKU_Id`
`,POS.PositionInStore`
`,CASE WHEN RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY TR.SKU_Id ORDER BY TR.SKU_Id`
`ASC ,POS.PositionInStore  ASC) = 1 THEN TR.nr_transactions ELSE NULL END`
`FROM TransactionTable TR RIGHT OUTER JOIN PositionTable POS`
`ON POS.SKU_Id = TR.SKU_Id ORDER BY 1,2;`
 and it gives the desired output table.